# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask to call yahooweather API. Following is the code:

```
public class myactivity extends Activity {
    final String yahooapisBase = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select*from%20geo.places%20where%20text=";
    final String yahooapisFormat = "&format=xml";
    String yahooAPIsQuery;
```

`EditText input_city;
EditText input_zip;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
    Button btn_findout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_findout);
    input_city = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_cityOrcountry);
    input_zip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_zip);

    // when Zip textbox has focus
    input_zip.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                String string = "";
                input_city.setText(string);
            }
        }
    });

    // when city/country textbox has focus
    input_city.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                String string = "";
                input_zip.setText(string);
            }
        }
    });

    // when findout button is clicked
    btn_findout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
            String uriPlace = Uri.encode(input_city.getText().toString());
            yahooAPIsQuery = yahooapisBase + "%22" + uriPlace + "%22"
                    + yahooapisFormat;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Before entering into sub thread", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            new WeatherAPITask().execute(yahooAPIsQuery);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "After sub thread",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i("my label", "back in main thread...");
            // String woeidString = QueryYahooWeather(yahooAPIsQuery);
            // input_city.setText(woeidString);
        }
    });
}

private String QueryYahooWeather(String queryString) {

    String qResult = "";

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(queryString);

    try {
        Log.i("WeatherApp", "digging into try block...");
        Log.i("queryString", queryString);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpClient.execute(httpGet).getEntity();

        if (httpEntity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
            Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(in);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String stringReadLine = null;

            while ((stringReadLine = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(stringReadLine + "\n");
            }

            qResult = stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Returning from function",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return qResult;

}

private class WeatherAPITask extends AsyncTask {

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("my label", "entering in onPostExecute");
        Log.i("result", result);
        input_city.setText("result");
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Log.i("my label", "entering in doInBackground");
            Log.i("params[0]", params[0].toString());
            return QueryYahooWeather(params[0].toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("my label", e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}`

}

After debugging the code I found that the yahooAPI call is successfull and I can see the XML response in `QueryYahooWeather` function. But as soon as execution of this function completes an exception has been thrown:
`Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all Toast's from `QueryYahooWeather` method because this method is called from `doInBackground(Object... params)` of `AsyncTask` and you can not Access Ui elements like Toast(also an Ui element)from background Thread.

**NOTE :** if you want to known what's going on in background then use [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) instead of Toast's

EDIT:

Change doInBackground as :

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String strresult="";
    try {
        Log.i("my label", "entering in doInBackground");
        Log.i("params[0]", params[0].toString());
         strresult= QueryYahooWeather(params[0].toString());
         Log.i("strresult result ::: ", strresult);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("my label", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
 return strresult;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. By removing toasts from that function the error has gone. But after returning from `QueryYahooWeather` its result is not returned, instead null value is returned in doInBackground method. Any ideas?

Comment: @NidaSulheri : put a log `Log.v(TAG, "QueryYahooWeather ::" + qResult); `before `return qResult;` in `QueryYahooWeather` and check you are getting value in qResult or not

Comment: I have checked `qResult` in debugging and it contains the whole resultant XML response.

Comment: and i think you also  change return type of `protected Object doInBackground(Object... params)` to `protected String doInBackground(Object... params) `

Comment: I have changed the return type of doInBackground to String but still null value is returned :(

Comment: @NidaSulheri : also check logcat what you are getting in Log.i("strresult result ::: ", strresult); this line

Comment: it solved that issue. I am marking your answer correct. I have although a minor issue left which I would appreciate if you try to resolve. It seems that `onPostExecute` method has to be called from main UI but I really dont know how to invoke it from main UI by passing the resultant response string `qResult`. thanks

Comment: @NidaSulheri :`onPostExecute method has to be called from main UI` this line means you can put your UI related code inside onPostExecute  or you can also access all Ui element from onPostExecute. what you want to do with resultant response you are getting in onPostExecute?

Comment: I have a edittext field `input_city`. I want to set resultant text to this input field. How can i do it?

Comment: @NidaSulheri :  have u try `input_city.setText(result);` inside `onPostExecute` instead of `input_city.setText("result");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20473/discussion-between-imran-khan-and-nida-sulheri)

Answer (score 1):

you are calling

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
```

in `QueryYahooWeather` which is being called in `doInBackground`.

You can not call `UI` calls from background thread.

Comment: thanks for your response. By removing toasts from that function the error has gone. But after returning from QueryYahooWeather its result is not returned, instead null value is returned in doInBackground method. Any ideas?